# Getting percentage of customers from a city

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve the percentage of registered customers that reside in certain cities.

Currently I have this

```
SELECT
COUNT(city) / Count(CustID) * 100 AS percent, city
FROM customer
GROUP BY City
```

It currently provides a result of 100% for each row.
I am missing something obvious here. How can I fix my query?

Comment: in your count count(city) and count(custId) give same output thats why you got 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the total number of customers in a separate subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(city) / (SELECT Count(CustID) FROM Customer) * 100 AS percent, city
FROM customer
GROUP BY City
```

or, using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
COUNT(city) / x.cnt * 100 AS percent, city
FROM customer
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Count(CustID) AS cnt FROM Customer) AS x
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: your subquery give the customer id of all cities

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT
COUNT(city) / (SELECT Count(CustID) FROM Customer) * 100 AS percent, city
FROM customer c
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: This will ouput 100% just like the query of the OP.

Comment: Correct, it provided 100% on all